# Don't start the route if the execution of the previous route is not finished

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot, apache-camel

I'm looking for a solution in apache camel for the problem in the code below.
the route cannot be started again until it has completed its previous run.

```
@Override
public void configure() throws Exception {
    from("timer://foo?fixedRate=true&period=3s")
            .routeId("teste")
            .log("INIT")
            .delay(5000)
            .log("DELAY-END")
            .end();
}
```

---

[image]

Comment: Apache Camel is pure evil, that's my personal opinion, you can disagree :)

Answer (score 1):

> You can let the Delayer use non blocking asynchronous delaying, which means Camel will use a scheduler to schedule a task to be executed in the future. The task will then continue routing. This allows the caller thread to not block and be able to service other messages etc.

Straight from the [docs](https://camel.apache.org/manual/latest/delay-eip.html#_asynchronous_delaying). Add `.asyncDelayed()` right after `.delay(5000)` to enable non-blocking behavior.